# How does Ahoy's visit work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ahoy

I want to track the visit clicking my links.

I need to know the percentage of browser, OS... of every link.

Does it mean I should add that in `link.rb` ?

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :visits 
end
```

But after clicking links lots of times, the links' visits aren't generated.

I really don't know how Ahoy's visit work, when to create a new visit.

Answer (score 0):

you need user model that will have many visits

putting the line below in the desired view will track visit for this view and create new Visit object record

```
ahoy.track("Viewed book", {title: "The World is Flat"});
```

if you want to track event easily, just use ajax call to create event

```
function sendTracker(vars) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/ahoy/events",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    async:false,
    data: {
          name: vars[0],
          properties: vars[1],
          time: timeNow,
          visit_id: <%= current_visit.nil? ? 0 : current_visit.id %>
          },
    success:function(){
    }
  });
```

this will create Ahoy::Event object with the parameters you choose

Finally, I needed to track with Ahoy AND to track event for ab testing (vanity). In this case I used intermediate technic

in the view

```
  <%= link_to "#{ab_test(:campaign_1_cta)}",{:controller => :campaigns, :action => :rich_link, :url => "http://url.to/redirect", :name => "cp1_cta", :props => "data", :abtest => ":cp1_click"} %>
```

and my campaigns controller

```
  def rich_link
    ahoy.track(params[:name], params[:props])
    var = params[:abtest].parameterize.underscore.to_sym
    Vanity.track!(var)
    redirect_to params[:url]
  end
```